# ListBoxItem inside a listbox not stretching completly to screen width

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, listbox

```
 <Grid Name="FavouriteStations" Visibility="Visible" >
    <ListBox  Name="FavouriteStationsListBox"   ItemsSource="{Binding}" Loaded="FavouriteStationsListBoxLoaded"  >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:StationTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                    <local:StationTemplateSelector.St>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid  MinHeight="150" MinWidth="480" Background="#242224"  >

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:StationTemplateSelector.St>
                    <local:StationTemplateSelector.Ad>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid  MinHeight="150" MinWidth="480" Background="#FFFFFF"  >

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:StationTemplateSelector.Ad>
                </local:StationTemplateSelector>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I have a `listbox` with multiple data templates.It is fine in portrait orientation, but when I change it to landscape the `listboxitem` height is automatically set to `MinHeight` and width to `MinWidth` but I want the width to be same as the screen width I tried the following

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But the `ListBoxItem` has the same width and height and the only difference I see that it is aligned to the center of the screen. How can I fix this ?[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. The issue was caused by the `DataTemplateSelector`, you have to set the `Template` value for the `DataTemplateSelector`(StationTemplateSelector) you are using in the section `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>` for this to work.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<Style TargetType="local:StationTemplateSelector">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:StationTemplateSelector">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
```

also need to set the `ItemContainerStyle` inside your `ListBox` control

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
     </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```